How to setup an internal email server?
As Microsoft will be retiring basic auth for SMTP I thought I would try to setup an internal e-mail server (on Docker) to basically allow applications in my home lab to send emails using an internal email system rather than a paid for service (like SMTP2GO).
For example, I use Open Media Vault which sends email notifications. What I would like is for it to send an e-mail via an internal server which I could view through Outlook 365 ( having Outlook 365 pick up the email from my local internal email sever).
Effectively then never having to open up ports to the internet as all such e-mail traffic to and from my internal server would be internal only.
I tried to find examples of this online, and use some AI tools to generate instructions, but did not succeed.

So my first question, is… Is this even possible?
And assuming it is, how is the best way to approach it (and/or is this documented in instructions or a youtube video that you could share)?


"Is this even possible" questions should be answered by a web search, to be honest. There are mail server software you can find via these web searches. The question of accessing a given local server via an email client is also going to be a pretty simple search. I'd guess the answer will be "yes", because email is email. But I'd also recommend you consider an alternate client such as Thunderbird, which will be more likely to be more compatible with an adhoc local email server.

Further, asking that we find you a how to document or video is definitely off topic on this site. We aren't librarians here, to point you to resources elsewhere. This community is about helping people solve problems by providing good answers to good questions.

What you describe sounds like deploying an Exchange server since you want to use Outlook 365

@Ramhound I believe Outlook, even the 365 version, supports connecting SMTP servers.

@music2myear - It might but Microsoft is retiring basic smtp authentication.

@Ramhound: They're retiring it for Outlook as in the mail provider (the artist previously known as Hotmail), not for Outlook the mail client.

I was able to get it to work using docker-mailserver for the mail server. It was easy to setup on Thunderbird, but I got it setup on Outook too (just a little finicky - the process of adding an account threw an error - but when I went back and edited the account to the same values it worked ??). In any case if anyone else is interested this page was very helpful as was this video.
For Outlook 365 (client) here are the steps to setup access:

File -> Info -> Add Account
Email address: (Enter full email address for internal sever - for example I used rob@docker.local where rob was the user id I setup on the docker-mailserver, and docker is the host name of the server itself.)
Checked “Let me set up my account manually.”
Clicked Connect
Clicked IMAP
incoming mail server:  docker.local
Port: 143
Encryption Method: None
uncheck Require logon using SPA

outgoing mail server:  docker.local
Port: 587
Encryption Method: None
uncheck Require logon using SPA


Click Next
Password (Entered password for the docker-mailer id rob@docker.local.)
Click Connect

An error message was thrown - but at the same time I the email send worked?

In any case, I then clicked: Go back
And then clicked: Next
And: Connect

And it worked with the account being added to my list of accounts in Outlook 365.


So my first question, is… Is this even possible?

Yes, in general, there is nothing about mail servers that would require them to be accessible from the Internet. In fact it's the other way around; a mail server usually starts with local-only delivery before one connects it to the Internet.
(For example, Debian Linux used to come with Exim as part of default installation, with one step away from becoming an SMTP listener.)
Whether your Outlook mail client will support this is a different question. Nearly all desktop mail clients will connect to any local IMAP service without much complaining, and I'm sure that "Outlook 2021 LTS" also does, but I've heard that "New Outlook" – aka rebranded "Windows 10 Mail" – was at least partially 'cloud'-based, and I don't know where "Outlook 365" stands in all of this.
The two components you need are an SMTP service that would receive messages from your various systems and an IMAP service that would let Outlook or other mail client apps access that mail. Traditionally on Linux/other Unix-like systems those are two separate things, though some newer Linux mail systems, as well as most Windows mail servers, have both functions integrated into one.
Using the traditional software on Linux, you might start with an SMTP service (e.g. Postfix, Exim, OpenSMTPd), then add an IMAP service (e.g. Dovecot, Cyrus).
In a fully internal setup you don't need SPF/DKIM/DMARC as the mail isn't being sent to external sites, or for that matter even DNS MX records as other sites aren't sending mail to you either. You should at least have some kind of DNS though, if only to avoid hardcoding the SMTP server's IP address everywhere, but it is possible to use an internal made-up domain so long as all systems agree on it.
